# Natural Gas Ventless Fireplace fittings in a fire pit and switch it to LP

Tags: fireplace, fire-pit

I have an old Natural Gas ventless fireplace that I never used.  I now want to build a fire pit and am wondering if I could take the working parts out of the fireplace unit and use those for fire pit.  I have already disassembled the fireplace and have included a photo of the parts. I plan on covering the fittings with fire glass.

I have attached a couple of images, but, have more detailed ones too of the individual parts, if needed.

Any suggestions or comments would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
[image]
[image]

Comment: Natural gas and LP gas often need different orifices for proper air-fuel mixtures.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change the gas orifice to a smaller size on the output of the control valve to the burner. You will also need to make sure the regulator from the tank to the control valve is 1/2 psi, other than that should work great.

Comment: Wonderful!  I have seen the conversion kits at Lowes.  I will take a look at those and make sure I change both the output and the control valve regulator, if needed. Thanks!